# Automating published PowerBI Dashboard

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I might be barking up the wrong tree entirely here, but this is what I am attempting to do, apologies if my terminology is wrong.

I have a dataset with two queries, one of these updates twice a day and the CSV file is sent to me by email.

I have a Power Automate flow that extracts the attachment from the received email and saves it to the SharePoint folder where the data (and PBIX) is kept.

I have a second Power Automate flow that triggers when a file in that SharePoint folder is modified. This is triggering when the attachment is saved ... that all appears to be working as expected.

BUT - the published report accessible by my colleagues isn't refreshed, the data remains the same. The flow is running, the report is not updated as expected.

I've added a card with a "last refresh date" and I can see that this date isn't being updated in the published report and as far as I can see neither is the actual data.

In PowerBI Desktop, I refresh then have to publish. Am I trying to do something, in my ignorance, that is not possible?

Comment: In the second power automate, how are you refreshing the report? Are you calling the power bi api to refresh the data loaded in the folder

Comment: I was using the Power Automate Refresh A Dataset - PowerBI Step